# Angular 4 - How to apply the rendered height of a div to another div?

Tags: angular, elementref

I have two named templates. I want to apply the height of the first one to the second one whenever the contents of the first one change. I can access both of them using ElementRef inside the component. So, when I change the properties bound to the first template, I use the corresponding ElementRef to get its height and apply it to the second template's ElementRef.

Now, the problem is that, after the property change, the height that I get from the ElementRef corresponding to the first template is not the updated height. It returns the height of the div before the property change and re-rendering.

I want to be able to get the actual rendered height after the div is updated. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

The code:

```
var height = `${this.profile.nativeElement.offsetHeight}px`;
this.renderer.setStyle(this.board.nativeElement, "height", height);
this.renderer.setStyle(
this.board.nativeElement,
"overflow-y",
"scroll"
);
```

Here ***profile*** is the ElementRef corresponding to the first div and ***board*** the ElementRef of second one. After property change, I call the function containing the above code. Then the height I get is the old height of the div, that is, before the property change and re-rendering.

Comment: Tried `element.offsetHeight;` ?

Comment: Yes. I am able to set the height and everything. The problem is that I don't get the updated height after the div is re-rendered.

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew: check $apply . May be you are missing digest cycle and hence you arent getting updated value

Comment: @ShashankVivek Can you elaborate on how to use $apply? I am using Angular 4.

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew: You had the wrong tag of "angularjs". Can you share your Angular 4 code so that we can see the actual code. Try `tick()` function for change detection cycle.

Comment: @ShashankVivek Added the code in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Access the ElementRef corresponding to each div using @ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild("profile") profile;
@ViewChild("board") board;
```

Implement **AfterViewChecked** and do the following in **ngAfterViewChecked**:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { 
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.profile && this.board) {
    var height = `${this.profile.nativeElement.offsetHeight}px`;
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.board.nativeElement, "height", height);
  }
}
```

*renderer* is **Renderer2** available in *@angular/core*